# Empty a folder with a system command with PHP

Tags: php, shell, directory

I use that system command to remove a folder and its content :

```
system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($path))
```

But I don't know how to remove only its content. I tried this, but the folder is still full :

```
system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($path.'/*'))
```

Any idea ?

Comment: +1 for using `escapeshellarg()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
system('/bin/rm -rf ' . escapeshellarg($path) . '/*')
```

*Why?*

`escapeshellarg()` will quote `$path`, wich will lead in your code to the shell command:

```
rm -rf '/path/*'
```

and the shell - that `system()` internally calls - won't expand `*` anymore.

Comment: You are welcome! Better you escape once too much then once too less... ;)

Answer (score 0):

This does not work, because you are escaping the asterisk, which results in bash ignoring it. But to get your expected result, bash needs to expand the asterisk to all files in the directory.

For further information visit http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion